# want to include animation in my application android

Tags: android, animation

I am developing an android game where balls are floating on the screen or falling from above.

I  have no idea on doing this animation as i am new to android, can you guys help me with this animation thing on how to do this.

I want to make the balls fall from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try android game engines, they are set of classes to develop games. try andengine thats the best one i know but not a nice tutorial is available although you can see examples and learn from them.

Comment: only 2D animation support in andengine

Comment: wat these game engines of? really no idea

Comment: google it..you will find answer, here is the link to tutorial i am using..https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/